# Wierd execution of if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Else condition is executed every time. If input is '11' answer is 'f' not 'D', I know  the last condition should be else if but according to the logic of input is 11 output should be 'D'

```
function getGrade(score) {
let grade;
var score1 = Number(score);
// Write your code here
if (score1 > 25 && score <= 30)
grade = "A";
else if (score1 > 20 && score <= 25)
grade = "B";  
else if (score1 > 15 && score <= 20)
grade = "C";
else if (score1 > 10 && score <= 15)
grade = "D";      
else if (score1 > 5 && score <= 10)
grade = "E";
else  (score1 > 0 && score <= 5)
grade = "F";
return grade;
}
```

Comment: You're comparing to a string, compare to a number instead.

Comment: Having two variables named `score` and `score1` is a terrible idea

Comment: I don't understand why you use `score` too

Comment: it looks like a part of an online course with *"// Write your code here"*.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a copy-paste? Then it's a matter of typo.

```
else  (score1 > 0 && score <= 5)
grade = "F";
```

`if` is missing here. Therefore, `(score1 > 0 && score <= 5)` is interpreted as the thing to do (so, evaluate an expression), and the next line is outside of any else/if branch and simply gets executed always.

Comment: Liked the explanation of why he got always "F" because of the evaluating statement.. Nice answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parenthesis around the `else if`. Also for the last condition you can simple use `else` instead of  `else if`

```js
function getGrade(score) {
  let grade;
  var score1 = Number(score);
  console.log(score1)
  // Write your code here
  if (score1 > 25 && score <= 30) {
    grade = "A";
  } else if (score1 > 20 && score <= 25) {
    grade = "B";
  } else if (score1 > 15 && score <= 20) {
    grade = "C";
  } else if (score1 > 10 && score <= 15) {
    grade = "D";
  } else if (score1 > 5 && score <= 10) {
    grade = "E";
  } else {
    grade = "F";
  }
  return grade;
}

console.log(getGrade(11))
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach, is to use an [*early exit paradigm*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18454/188454), starting with wrong values and then take a ladder of conditions which rely on the conditions before.

```
function getGrade(score) {
    var score1 = Number(score);

    if (isNaN(score1) || score1 > 30 || score1 < 0) return;
    if (score1 > 25) return "A";
    if (score1 > 20) return "B";
    if (score1 > 15) return "C";
    if (score1 > 10) return "D";
    if (score1 > 5) return "E";
    return "F";
}
```